# Python If last N values of list is same as last N values of list 2

Tags: python, list, compare

**I am doing practice past paper questions to revise for my exam next week**

Let's say i have two lists

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[1,2,3,4]
```

and a variable n set to a value i.e. 2
I need to create a function that checks if the last "n" values are the same in list1 and list2 in the same order.

**One variant using a for loop and one without a loop**

In this case it would return true, since 3,4 are the same in list 1 and 2

If b=[1,2,4,3] it would return false

My current code without a loop is:

```
def compare1(a,b,n):
    if a[-n:]==b[-n:]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I believe this works when i test it

But how would i convert this to have a for loop aswell? If i add:

```
def compare2(a,b,n):
    for i in a and b:
        if a[-n:]==b[-n:]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

this would work but the for loop isn't doing anything

Comment: Hint: your loop expression should involve both `range` and `n`.

Comment: @godlypython you need to iteratively check for inequaliries or last n elements and return False if any if them is false af  return True if all `n` elements are equal.Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. You could loop over the indices of the lists, or you could zip the lists together and loop directly over the items. Here are a few examples. I've also optimised your `compare1` function.

```
def compare1(a, b, n):
    return a[-n:] == b[-n:]

def compare2(a, b, n):
    for i in range(-n, 0, 1):
        if a[i] != b[i]:
            return False
    return True

def compare3(a, b, n):
    for u, v in zip(a[-n:], b[-n:]):
        if u != v:
            return False
    return True

def compare4(a, b, n):
    return all(u == v for u, v in zip(a[-n:], b[-n:]))

# test

funcs = (compare1, compare2, compare3, compare4)

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 3, 4]
c = [1, 2, 5, 6]

for compare in funcs:
    print(compare.__name__)
    print(a, b, compare(a, b, 2))
    print(a, c, compare(a, c, 2))
    print()
```

**output**

```
compare1
[1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 3, 4] True
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 5, 6] False

compare2
[1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 3, 4] True
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 5, 6] False

compare3
[1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 3, 4] True
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 5, 6] False

compare4
[1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 3, 4] True
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 5, 6] False
```

FWIW, `compare1` is the best way to do this, since it does all the looping & testing at the C level rather than using explicit Python code.

Comment: Could you clarify one thing for me please in compare2, within the range function, lets say my value of n is 2. If my starting is -2, and it goes upto 0 (would that not be the start of the range?) when we are comparing the ends?

Comment: @godlypython `range` _never_ includes the `stop` value. So if `n` is 2, then the loop only compares the `[-2]` and `[-1]` items in `a` and `b`, it never gets to `[0]` (which would be the first item in the list). And of course it `return`s out of the loop early if it finds a pair of items that aren't equal.

Comment: @godlypython range(-5,0,1) is   -5,-4,-3,-2,-1 . stop value is not included

Answer (score 0):

**Without loop**

```
def compare1(a,b,n):
    return a[-n:] == b[-n:]
```

**With loop**
You need to iterate from last to `nth` from last

```
def compare2(a,b,c):
    for i in xrange(1,c + 1):
        if a[-i] != b[-i]:
            return False
    return True
```